# MWS API Update Inventory Stock?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-mws

I am working with MWS API [REST]. For this i am using MWS Client libraries.I want to update the inventory Stock. i Searched all over the internet but could not found anything except.

we have to use FEED's API to update the stock.But in feed's API there is only POST request. And we have to update the stock using this API
https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html

and we have to upload the file to update the stock.
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/mws-api-update-inventory-stock/125649

My Question is that can we update the stock with another API ? or we have to upload the file to update the stock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must use a feed to update inventory, the inventory feed.  Here is a link to some more information about this API: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html?itemID=200386820&